# How to print / console log props in constructor method in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Folks,

Please help me in a way to print/console props in the constructor. I have tried console.log(this.props) but not sure where it is getting printed.

I am using the android simulator for react-native development.

Please help.

Comment: Are you asking about setting up devtools?

Comment: I want to see the output of console.log(), where can I view? . Native Android app development, I was using adb logcat. something similar with React-native.

Comment: If someone downvote the question, please mention the reason to downvote. As there is already an accepted answer, why do anyone want to down vote?

Answer (score 4):

You can see the console using the "Debug JS remotely" option on the emulator menu, but I strongly recommend the standalone app called "React native debugger"

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

You can see not only the console logs but also the components information, their props, styles, the network tab, the redux actions, states, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, if you're asking how to bring up the console?

On Android emulator, Once your app has started, press 
CMD + M to bring up the options and select "Debug JS remotely" which will automatically start the debugger on chrome

Answer (score 1):

The output of console.log is getting printed here for Android simulator and devices

Open Terminal and run the following command :-

```
 $ react-native log-android
```

Now run the app on simulator or device, you will see the logs.

You will see the logs inside the terminal.

Similarly can do for iOS as follows:-

```
$ react-native log-ios
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A **Pure React Component** can be declared as follows:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       console.log(props)
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In the code above it will show you the props object being passed to the component.

In your case you must be using object/function approach to define a component, which results in a scope confusion of `this`.